# Counting spaces after a specific letter

Tags: count, space, specifications, letter

I want to count the spaces after the letter T or t.

text:

```
Mr oh winding it enjoyed by between. The servants securing material goodness her. \
Saw principles themselves ten are possession. So endeavor to continue
```

Comment: The first occurrence, or each occurrence? More generally, what output do you expect for the example text?

Comment: For each occurrence.  Output would be "1" for the example text.

Comment: Those two responses are contradictory. The example text has 9 occurrences of 'T' or 't'. So the first sentence implies an output with 9 numbers, whereas the second sentence only has one.

Comment: I need count the spaces after T or t with phyton code, and in this example there is only one space occurs after t. I don't understand what did you mean?

Comment: The phrase "count the spaces" in your problem statement suggested that you wanted the number of spaces after each T or t. I now think you want the number of times that the text contains a T or t followed by a space. Is that correct?

Comment: What I mean is, for example  in the example text there is "winding it" and after t there is once space, so the result is 1. Because in whole text space doesn't occur just after T or t. I hope this time I managed to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions, then `[Tt]` is the pattern for "a T or t followed by a space". To count the number of occurrences of this pattern in a text, you can write:

```
len(re.findall('[Tt] ', text))
```

If you don't want to use regular expressions, then you can write:

```
text.count('T ') + text.count('t ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using regEx. Check all your scenarios are covered.

[Check Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2IE0GHCVI5A)